# exif when uploading pictures with php on a mobile device stripping GPS header?

Tags: php, iphone, file-upload, jpeg, exif

I have a script to upload photos to a website written in PHP. When I upload a picture using Safari on my IPhone, some of the header appears to be stripped when I check the exif data. When I take the exact same picture from my IPhone and email it to myself and upload it from a computer, all of the exif data is there.

I was wondering if there was a setting on the IPhone or a PHP script that I am missing that will let me grab the GPS part of the exif when I try to upload from my IPhone. All I want is to grab the GPS array from the exif_read_data when I upload pictures to my website through my IPhone.

An Exif example from my Safari on Iphone:

```
Image type is: JPEG

FILE.FileName: 20130417141031image.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1366225831
FILE.FileSize: 1692449
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF
COMPUTED.html: width="3264" height="2448"
COMPUTED.Height: 2448
COMPUTED.Width: 3264
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
IFD0.Orientation: 6
IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 38
EXIF.ColorSpace: 1
EXIF.ExifImageWidth: 3264
EXIF.ExifImageLength: 2448
```

An Exif example of the same image uploaded from my PC taken by the same phone:

```
Image type is: JPEG

FILE.FileName: 20130417142504image.jpeg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1366226835
FILE.FileSize: 1744896
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF, GPS
COMPUTED.html: width="3264" height="2448"
COMPUTED.Height: 2448
COMPUTED.Width: 3264
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
COMPUTED.ApertureFNumber: f/2.4
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.FileType: 2
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.MimeType: image/jpeg
IFD0.Make: Apple
IFD0.Model: iPhone 4S
IFD0.Orientation: 6
IFD0.XResolution: 72/1
IFD0.YResolution: 72/1
IFD0.ResolutionUnit: 2
IFD0.Software: 6.1.3
IFD0.DateTime: 2013:04:17 15:13:39
IFD0.YCbCrPositioning: 1
IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 204
IFD0.GPS_IFD_Pointer: 594
THUMBNAIL.Compression: 6
THUMBNAIL.XResolution: 72/1
THUMBNAIL.YResolution: 72/1
THUMBNAIL.ResolutionUnit: 2
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 890
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 7684
EXIF.ExposureTime: 1/20
EXIF.FNumber: 12/5
EXIF.ExposureProgram: 2
EXIF.ISOSpeedRatings: 50
EXIF.ExifVersion: 0221
EXIF.DateTimeOriginal: 2013:04:17 15:13:39
EXIF.DateTimeDigitized: 2013:04:17 15:13:39
EXIF.ComponentsConfiguration: 
EXIF.ShutterSpeedValue: 2779/643
EXIF.ApertureValue: 4845/1918
EXIF.BrightnessValue: 13523/4727
EXIF.MeteringMode: 3
EXIF.Flash: 16
EXIF.FocalLength: 107/25
EXIF.SubjectLocation: Array
EXIF.FlashPixVersion: 0100
EXIF.ColorSpace: 1
EXIF.ExifImageWidth: 3264
EXIF.ExifImageLength: 2448
EXIF.SensingMethod: 2
EXIF.ExposureMode: 0
EXIF.WhiteBalance: 0
EXIF.FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 35
EXIF.SceneCaptureType: 0
GPS.GPSLatitudeRef: N
GPS.GPSLatitude: Array
GPS.GPSLongitudeRef: W
GPS.GPSLongitude: Array
GPS.GPSAltitudeRef: 
GPS.GPSAltitude: 55556/297
GPS.GPSTimeStamp: Array
GPS.GPSImgDirectionRef: T
GPS.GPSImgDirection: 19688/145
```

Here is the code that I use for my PHP script for photos, I removed the header and requires:

```
<?php
require('[...]');
mysql_select_db($db_name, $oConn);

$JobNum = $_POST['JobNum'];

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        ps_log( "Bad Photo Upload - Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"]);
    }
    else
    {
        ps_log( "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        ps_log( "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"]);
        ps_log( "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb");
        ps_log( "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />");

        $photoname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $root = "[...]";
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$root.$photoname;
        $exif = exif_read_data($photoname, 0, true);

        $filename = $exif["FILE"]["FileName"];
        $model = $exif["IFD0"]["Model"];
        $date = $exif["IFD0"]["DateTime"];
        $lon = $exif["GPS"]["GPSLongitude"];
        $lonref = $exif["GPS"]['GPSLongitudeRef'];
        $lat = $exif["GPS"]["GPSLatitude"];
        $latref = $exif["GPS"]['GPSLatitudeRef'];


        $lon = Photos::getGps($lon, $lonref);
        $lat = Photos::getGps($lat, $latref);

        $photo = new UploadedPhoto();
        $photo->JobNum = $JobNum;
        $photo->TempFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $photo->FileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $photo->Comments = $_POST['Comment'];
          $photo->Model = $model ;
  $photo->DateStamp = $date ;
  $photo->Lat = $lat ;
  $photo->Lng = $lon ;
        $photo->SaveGeo();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}

header("[...]");?>
```

Comment: Uploading files to a website has always been weird in iOS. Stripping the personal data is a "feature" of iOS, not a bug. https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=image+upload+iphone+exif

Comment: I'm using rails and jquery-file-upload for my site and I have the same issue as you do. The same image file upload from pc has full EXIF info whereas from iPhone only has basic info (no GPS info). It's sad.

Comment: I believe the reason for this is privacy concerns for people uploading pictures to social network and such - to prevent giving away the location of children to strangers, etc. There's nothing on the server side that you can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image upload from iphone strips exif data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297730/image-upload-from-iphone-strips-exif-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing you can do is to create a native app (or Apache Cordova app), that will handle the upload. The GPS data is stripped by mobile Safari. Your app should upload the picture as-is. As of now there is no other way around it.

It may be something along these lines: http://gonzalo123.com/2013/10/28/taking-photos-with-a-phonegapcordova-application-and-uploading-them-to-the-server/