# Drupal 7, iPhone image orientation messed up - no exif information

Tags: iphone, image, drupal-7, exif, autorotate

So, I have been losing my mind with this for two days now. I have a site built on Drupal 7.

The issue I have is that when my site users upload images from iPhone or iPad *(both through ckeditor AND account profile images uploaded through forms)* images end up being turned upside down.

I have gone as far as writing independent php to read exif data of images and detect the problem when I noticed a bizarre issue. images DO have exif information when not in drupal and it seems like they lose exif information once uploaded to drupal.

I use this code to read exif information

```
$full_filename ='image.jpg';
$exif = exif_read_data($full_filename);

print "<pre>";
    print_r($exif);
print "<pre>";
```

This is a result read from an image that was not uploaded to drupal

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => image4.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1372430458
    [FileSize] => 1568098
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="2592" height="1936"
            [Height] => 1936
            [Width] => 2592
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 1
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/2.8
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [Make] => Apple
    [Model] => iPhone 4
    [Orientation] => 6
    [XResolution] => 72/1
    [YResolution] => 72/1
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => 5.1.1
    [DateTime] => 2013:06:28 09:18:53
    [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 192
    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 72/1
            [YResolution] => 72/1
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 676
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 8886
        )

    [ExposureTime] => 1/24
    [FNumber] => 14/5
    [ExposureProgram] => 2
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 80
    [ExifVersion] => 0221
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2013:06:28 09:18:53
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 2013:06:28 09:18:53
    [ComponentsConfiguration] => 
    [ShutterSpeedValue] => 21632/4717
    [ApertureValue] => 4281/1441
    [BrightnessValue] => 94810/26881
    [MeteringMode] => 5
    [Flash] => 24
    [FocalLength] => 77/20
    [SubjectLocation] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1295
            [1] => 967
            [2] => 699
            [3] => 696
        )

    [FlashPixVersion] => 0100
    [ColorSpace] => 1
    [ExifImageWidth] => 2592
    [ExifImageLength] => 1936
    [SensingMethod] => 2
    [ExposureMode] => 0
    [WhiteBalance] => 0
    [SceneCaptureType] => 0
    [Sharpness] => 2
)
```

and this is information from an image uploaded to drupal

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => image3.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1372355645
    [FileSize] => 75670
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1024" height="765"
            [Height] => 765
            [Width] => 1024
            [IsColor] => 1
        )

    [COMMENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 75

        )

)
```

Is it possible that drupal has something to do with this. The GD toolkit?

I tried using imagecache autorotate and it rotates images not uploaded from iphone but no luck with ipad or iphone ones.

I am unsure how to go about this to begin with. All help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing things.

iPhone/Pad strip the EXIF info when they send the image.

[Image upload from iphone strips exif data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297730/image-upload-from-iphone-strips-exif-data)

The EXIF Custom Module may be of help.

https://drupal.org/project/exif_custom

So might  ImageCache Actions

https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions