# using <input type="file" accept="image/*"> i want to know if the picture has been browsed or taken with the camera

Tags: javascript

using

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

I want to know if the picture has been browsed or taken with the camera on a mobile device.

Is there a way to get this information using javasript ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting EXIF data with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061122/extracting-exif-data-with-javascript)

Comment: Very interesting but it doesn't seem to give the origin of the photo.

Comment: That would be included in EXIF data.  Can you show what you have done or what you have tried? Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here on SO.