# Different EXIF for different smartphone

Tags: javascript, image, gps, exif, smartphone

I'm trying to write code in which I read the EXIF data for photographs being uploaded to our organisation.
It's the GPS tags that are of importance, but I'm running into a problem.
In order to read the data I've used 3 different libraries:

- piexif
- exifjs
- exifr

Next to testing these libraries in code, I've also tested all of the pictures in a multitude of online EXIF readers.

The GPS data for Android (Samsung I've specifically tested) is invalid, and the IPhone based pictures simply show to contain no EXIF.
Now I know they do contain at least some form of GEO tags, because on the devices themselves I can  see the picture marked on the map.

Now my question is, does the EXIF data differ per smartphone vendor?
And perhaps more to the point, how can I properly read the EXIF so to support all different versions?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm aiming to do this processing clientside.
And I've found out, that, in iOS when emailing pictures in the mail inline instead of attaching them the EXIF data gets excluded.

Edit2: It turns out that also android (or perhaps the email client "outlook") alters the EXIF data when sharing the picture.
While when using android the EXIF data doesn't entirely get truncated, the GPS data is set to 0 making it invalid.

When directly uploading the pictures when debugging with the smartphone, all 3 libraries where able to extract the necessary data.

Comment: You want to read it on the client or server. There are npm libraries for node for example

Comment: I wish to read it on the client in the browser (javascript).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061122/extracting-exif-data-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try this API that standarizes the output:

https://rapidapi.com/igniwork-igniwork/api/metadata-extractor/